# Link between 2 json data from $http in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have 2 http get JSON format data the first one:

```
category:2
city_code:"C!000871"
country:"TH"
hotel_code:"H!0532874"
name:"Chaulty Towers Guest House"
```

then depend on `hotel_code` I send another `$http.get` request and new data are as below:

```
 address:"149/41 Moo 4, Maret, Lamai 84310 Koh Samui   Moo 4, Maret, Lamai"
 category:"2"
 city_code:"C!000871"
 code:"H!0532874"
```

that `hotel_code` is same as `code` how I can show on view `address` from second data that match with `hotel_code`

ps:
in my view i Have `ng-repeat="data in data | limitTo: 10"` for first set of data.

Answer (score 2):

You can try  this : comments added :

```
// Iterate 1st Array
for (var i = 0; i < HouseNames.length; i++) {
    // Iterate 2nd Array
    for (var k = 0; k < HotelDetails.length; k++) {
        // Check for Hotel code
        if (HouseNames[i].hotel_code == HotelDetails[k].code) {
            // If hotel code matches add it to 1st array
            HouseNames[i].hotelDetails = HotelDetails[k];
        }
    }
}
console.log(HouseNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create some function to get the second data set from controller and then, make a map and show data using ng-repeat with the same array.

```
$scope.data = [your data here].map(function(item){
    get_2nd_json_resp_by_hotel_code(item.hotel_code).then(
        function(res){
            $scope.data = angular.extend($scope.data ,res);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Dear @Dody
Thanks for time and answer and sorry for my lack of knowledge but i dont undrestand this part :`get_2nd_json_resp_by_hotel_code` could please point me to correct direction

Comment: well, basically you need to get this second json using this code from somewhere, it's just a generic function in order to post the idea.